# PHP Date Comparison Not Working

Tags: php, date

I'm trying to understand why this code works:

```
<?php
// $today = date("d/m/Y");
$today = date("Y-m-d");
$today_dt = new DateTime($today);

foreach ($records as $record) {
}
?>

<tr>
    <?php $dueDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($record->getField('Due Date'))); ?>
    <td><?php echo 'today is: ' . $today; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo 'expiry date is: ' . $dueDate; ?></td>
    <td> <?php $expire_dt = new DateTime($dueDate); ?> </td>
    <td><?php echo $expire_dt < $today_dt ? 'expire time less than today time':'expire time greater than today time';?></td>
```

but when I change the format of the date from `Y-m-d` to `d/m/Y` this fails with an error:

```
<?php
// $today = date("d/m/Y");
$today = date("d/m/Y");
$today_dt = new DateTime($today);

foreach ($records as $record) {

}
?>

    <tr>
<?php $dueDate = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($record->getField('Due Date'))); ?>
    <td><?php echo 'today is: ' . $today; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo 'expiry date is: ' . $dueDate; ?></td>
    <td><?php $expire_dt = new DateTime($dueDate); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $expire_dt < $today_dt ? 'expire time less than today time' : 'expire time greater than today time';?></td>
```

The error is

> 'PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message
>   'DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (19/06/2015) at
>   position 0 (1)'

The line it references is:

```
$today_dt = new DateTime($today);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date format you used should be 'mm/dd/yyyy', not 'dd/mm/yyyy'.

Comment: Thanks - that works. I don't understand why I have to do that. Can you explain?

Comment: You can get the explaination at this page [date_create](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-create.php)

Answer (score 0):

Using the DateTime class you don't have to format the input date the way you want it to display, you can display it in any format using format.

```
// Get todays date
$today_dt = new DateTime();

// Display date in specified format
echo $today_dt->format('d/m/Y');
```

[Check out the PHP man page for more.](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)